# How to import a csv, makes it reactive and create plots

Tags: r, shiny, roc, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to create a shiny app that imports different csv's and create plots using for example the package pROC.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Column Plot"),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Upload File",
                 titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                   accept=c('text/csv', 
                                            'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                            '.csv')),
                         tags$br(),
                         checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                         radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                      c(Comma=',',
                                        Semicolon=';',
                                        Tab='\t'),
                                      ','),
                         radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                      c(None='',
                                        'Double Quote'='"',
                                        'Single Quote'="'"),
                                      '"')

                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         tableOutput('contents')
                     )
                 )
        ),
        tabPanel("First Type",
                 pageWithSidebar(
                     headerPanel('My First Plot'),
                     sidebarPanel(


                         selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', ""),
                         selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = "")

                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         plotOutput('MyPlot')
                     )
                 )
        )

    )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {



    data <- reactive({ 
        req(input$file1) 

        inFile <- input$file1 


        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)




        updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                          choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
        updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                          choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])

        return(df)
    })

    output$contents <- renderTable({
        data()
    })

    output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
        pROC::roc(input$xcol,input$ycol)

    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried to use different codes available in blogs, however, I did not find anything similar. It is possible to reproduce simple plots, like histograms but when I try to import the package proc for example there are always errors associated in this case: 'response' must have two levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` variable that you get in the server lists the *column names* in `xcol` and `ycol`. pROC's `roc` function expects the data itself, which you need to get from your data like for instance:

```
pROC::roc(x[[input$xcol]], x[[input$ycol]])
```